# Services: Which structure is a better idea?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, business-logic, object

I'm designing my service layer for a GraphQL API and there are many situations in which I can't decide if code relating to a table should belong in it's own class, or the class that 'owns' the data. For example, I could have a user class which can get a users appointments, products, etc...or I could have two classes: Appointments and Products.

```
UserService extends BaseService {
    constructor(user){
       this.user = user
    }
    getAppointments(){
       db.query('GET * FROM Appointments WHERE userId=this.user.id')
    }
    getProducts(){
       db.query('GET * FROM Products WHERE userId=this.user.id')
    }
}
```

```
AppointmentService extends BaseService {
    getAppointments(userId){
       db.query('GET * FROM Appointments WHERE userId=userId')
    }
}
ProductService extends BaseService {
    getProducts(userId){
       db.query('GET * FROM Products WHERE userId=userId')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can't decide, it's because you're not making your decision based on things that really "matter" to you.

If your objects would express the actual *behavior* of the application you're trying to build, it would be much easier to decide what belongs where. Objects that end with "Service", "Manager", etc. are a smell, especially because they are not well defined, *and* they're technical in nature.

Try to start with the *behavior* you want to support. Write the actual code you'll like to see. Then you'll have concrete evidence as to what you'll need to have. **There's no point designing something without knowing how it will be used.**

Answer (score 0):

Answering based on the example you provided.

Use separate classes for each table (e.g., Appointments and Products) if they have distinct business logic, require complex queries, or if you anticipate reusing or extending the functionality specific to those tables.

If on the other hand the relationships between the tables (e.g., a user's appointments or products) are relatively simple and don't involve complex business logic, you can consider including the relevant methods in the User class itself. This approach keeps the codebase simpler and avoids unnecessary class proliferation.